# go vet warns that example refers to unknown identifier, but why?

Tags: go

I have an `Extractor` interface that has a `Playlist` method:

```
// extractor.go
package extractor
type Extractor interface {
    Playlist(timestampFrom int64) (playlist.Tracklist, error)
}
```

I'm using this interface in another package:

```
// fip.go
package fip
type Extractor struct {
}

func (extractor Extractor) Playlist(timestampFrom int64) ([]playlist.Track, error) {
    // ...
}
```

And in my tests, I'd like to show an example on how to use the `Playlist` method for the `fip` package:

```
// fip_test.go
package fip
func ExamplePlaylist() { 
    // ...
}
```

But `go vet` shows this error:
`fip/extractor_test.go:82:1: ExamplePlaylist refers to unknown identifier: Playlist`

I don't understand why... `Playlist` does exist as a method in the `fip` package. What am I missing?

If more context is needed, see these files with the full source:

https://github.com/coaxial/tizinger/blob/8016d52a1278cf44dde13d518c6a15a18cb29774/extractor/extractor.go

https://github.com/coaxial/tizinger/blob/8016d52a1278cf44dde13d518c6a15a18cb29774/fip/fip.go

https://github.com/coaxial/tizinger/blob/8016d52a1278cf44dde13d518c6a15a18cb29774/fip/fip_test.go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct name for the example function is `ExampleExtractor_Playlist` as described in the [examples section](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples) of the testing docs.

Quoting:

```
The naming convention to declare examples for the package, a function F, a type T and method M on type T are:

func Example() { ... }
func ExampleF() { ... }
func ExampleT() { ... }
func ExampleT_M() { ... }
```

Your example is the last case where `T` is `Extractor` and `M` is `Playlist`.